# Talk about vs Talked about

Tags: passive-voice, transitivity, active-vs-passive

As far as i know, Transitive verb can only become passive

Well,

Look at this example

> - The mangers **talked about the problem**.
> - The problem was **talked about**.

As far as i am concerned, when a preposition isn’t part of the verb (phrasal verb), the verb cannot become passive because it loses the feature of transitivity.

The preposition **About** in the sentence doesn’t form a phrasal verb with talk; however, it can come in a passive form.

How can *talk about* come in a passive form?

Comment: While your question isn't completely clear to me (technically, in fact, what you have written doesn't seem to include a question), your premise appears to be that "to talk about" isn't a phrasal verb. Actually, though, it is, and it is also transitive. (In your first example, "the problem" is the direct object of "talk about.") Does that help?

Comment: Quite obviously **talk about** is a phrasal verb because it can be put into the passive.